# Directing user from one app script as an anonymous user to another app script behind a domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I am deeply into learning about App Script but there is so much the Google has to offer I'm a bit overwhelmed at figuring out what I need.

I'm designing an online volunteer application work-flow and eventually other things for a non-profit organization.

Here is how I envision the process flow going.

1. New user comes up first Web App page asks for first last middle and email address
2. First Last Middle are used together in some way to create a domain log on for the user using the provisioning API (already figured this part out) while prompting the user to create a password
3. At this point the user is passed to the actual application web app that runs only for domain users so that the relaxed rules of app script for user behind a domain can be leveraged and also so the entire ebb and flow of information stay behind our domain.

Now where I am unclear on is the jump from step 2 to step 3.

What would be the best and most painless (for the user not me) way to put together the transition from running the entry point app that creates the new users domain account as essentially an anonymous user identity to running the domain level app AS their new domain user identity.

I've been studying OAUTH but it seems that is more for external integration with things like drive and youtube etc. My goal with this project is to have everything (aside from things like client side validation and jQuery) running from Google's Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

In #2 i asusume you have a pool  of unused gapps accounts.
In #3 you need to get the user logged in in gapps first . For that you need to show a special login url that will redirect  to fhe other app.  Another is to do a manual oauth flow and use the redirect url to get to fhe new app.

Comment: Well we have the Google Apps for Education (non profit also) so we have an upper limit of i believe 3,000 users before we have to pay for it. Our current year round staff is maybe 50 and that's being generous. During the summer months we might double that number adding volunteers. even if we get 10 times the number of volunteers for the positions that's still only 500 new users. 

Bear in mind that those applicants that are rejected for what ever reason will be culled from the domain users. So I really do not see this app pushing us even close to a 1/3 of our user quota

Comment: Now you meantioned a manual OAuth flow. Would it be correct to assume that since the user will have provided their initial user name and password that I can take that information in my code and generate the OAuth tokens using GAS or does there have to be a separate manual process for the OAuth?  Also If I set up an OAuth flow for the new user does that take care of them going through the initial "welcome to your domain" deal the first time they login or is the OAuth flow smart enough to drop them back into the app after they click through that?